# RegEx Exclude specific character set but include everything else

Tags: regex, informatica

I am currently working in the Informatica Developer tool. Below is my current regex string.

`.+(?=[^S]?\/[^N]?|\/)`

I am trying to find and select everything before a forward slash (/) but exclude instances where the slash is preceded by an S and followed by an N.

For instance:

Nave 7 Avenida Olivo S/N - *No match found*

**Deschutes Rd /** Old 44 Drive - *Match found*

Comment: Do you have an example showing what you have tried?  What about your attempt did not work?

Comment: Try [`.+(?=(?<!S)\/(?!N))`](https://regex101.com/r/qX4fO8/1). This will match up to the *last* `/` that is not preceded with`S` and not followed with`N`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew This worked perfectly for instances of "S/N" and " / " (with spaces). However, it is also excluding "AnyAlphaChar/AnyAlphaChar". Example of data: Brinson Rd/Us 41 & Sr 54. Is there a way to also look for this?

Comment: What should be matched in `Brinson Rd/Us 41 & Sr 54`? Or it should not be matched? If not, why?

Comment: I'm working to cleanse address information. In order to do that, I am copying the address to the next line and removing everything before a match. In `Brinson Rd/Us 41 & Sr 54`, the match should be everything before the slash, `Brinson Rd`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit of simple regex that works:

```
(.+)(S\/N)|(.+)(\/)
```

The first set of parentheses capture your 'Nave 7...' instance.  The third set will capture your 'Deschutes Rd ' instance.

here's a link to where I was working on the regex:  [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/vF0oA9/3)

UPDATE:  Per your additional spec below, I'd change the regex to:

```
(.+)(S\/N)|(.+)(Suite|Unit|\/)
```

Again, ignore the capture of the 1st set of parens and use that of the 3rd set.

Comment: I am looking to expand the expression to look for more like Suite and Unit. Using your example, I tried this.
`(.+)(Suite)|(.+)(Unit)|(.+)(S\/N)|(.+)(\/)`
I would like to remove everything before the match and leave the match and everything following.

Comment: Do you have more example data?

Comment: Definitely.

**3864 Country St** Suite 240.  
**300 Laird St** Suite A.  
**211 Lanier Dr** Unit 1900.  

Currently, it is also matching the Suite and Unit as well. This is why I was trying to use the `(?=` for the positive lookahead in order to locate to the character string, but match to everything preceding it. Code: `.+(?=Suite|Unit)`. I would like to include in "/" but exclude instances of S/N.